# Get parent name of current category on category list pages in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have found several methods of obtaining the product id of a category while on a category list page, but none covering the best way to obtain the parent name of the category while on a category page. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I found this to be the quicker solution to retrieving the parent of the category.

```
<?php 
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
   echo $category->getParentCategory()->getName();
?>
```

Comment: This also doesn't work as it should for me - it doesn't get $category if I am on some category page. You know why?

Comment: Magento now recommends we not use object manager directly. You should create a module using the solution provided by Amit Bera.

Answer (score 4):

In Magento2,if you have an instance of *category object* then you *can get its parent category name by calling*  `$categoryObject->getParentCategory->getName()`.

If you want to ***show the parent category name on the phtml template of the category page*** then, in the Block class assigned to the phtml template,you *need to inject dependency to initialize magento registry class* `\Magento\Framework\Registry` in the Block class' *`__construct()`* and from  *current_category* get the current category object

> ```
>     protected $_registry;
>
>      /**
>       * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
>      */
>
>         public function __construct(
>             ...,
>             ...,
>             \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
>             ...
>         ) {
>             $this->_registry = $registry;
>             ...
>             ...
>         }
>
> /**
>  * Return catalog current category object
>  * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
>  */
>
> public function getCurrentCategoryOb()
> {
>     return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
> }
> ```

*Now at phtml file call this code  for getting parent category name:*

```
if($this->getCurrentCategoryOb()):
if($this->getCurrentCategoryOb()->getParentCategory()):
echo  $this->getCurrentCategoryOb()->getParentCategory())->getName();
endif
endif;
```

Comment: Where does the class code go?

Comment: Can  u please tell where are u want to show the code, exact section of category

Comment: Above the page-title block.

Comment: Can u please give me  screen shot of webpage where you want to add this

Comment: if I understand your question right, you want to get the product name on a category page? You can get the product name inside the product_list for each product like this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1d97cd9ddee038c9b93c43b74c8e318702a70a33/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml#L64 But, if you want to display the name in the page-title, how should magento know, which product of the category should go in the page title?

Comment: @DavidVerholen,please  add your comment AT QUESTION section ,not here?

Comment: i chose this place because the information with the page title is pretty important for it since this is the reason why it cannot really work

Comment: :)..........................

Comment: @DavidVerholen I just needed the parent name of the current category. Amit Bera thank you for your help.

Comment: @AmitBera, how to get parent category url?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to resolve your query:

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $current_category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
      $parent_category = $current_category->getParentCategory();
      echo $current_category->getName();
      echo $parent_category->getName(); ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it should for me - it doesn't echo current category if I am on some category. Instead, it displays as current category is some of parent categories.. You know why?

Comment: When category is selected by clicking on filters on layered navigation, it doesn't work.