# magento2 get category name in post category page

Tags: magento2.3

In file phtml i want to select category name. If i use

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
echo $category->getParentCategory()->getName();
```

I will have error: Call to a member function getParentCategory()

And when i use:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
if (method_exists($category, "getParentCategory")){
    echo $category->getParentCategory()->getName();
}
```

Don't have ouput Only a white screen

Please help me!

Comment: where you use this code?

Comment: i search and fint it here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101687/get-parent-name-of-current-category-on-category-list-pages-in-magento-2. I use it in title.phtml

Comment: i am asking on which page, you are trying

Comment: yes it page post view in category better blog

Comment: mageplease better blog?

Comment: Yes better blog